# Delphi.How to parse this xml?

Tags: xml, delphi

I have this XML :

```
<NET_TAX_DATABASE DeviceSerialNo="ATH16000038" CreationDate="15/11/2016 13:21">
<VAT>
<Code>02</Code>
<Letter>B</Letter>
<Percent>8%</Percent
<RcptVATAmount>31,11</RcptVATAmount>
</VAT>
<VAT>
<Code>03</Code>
<Descr>CATEG. TVA B</Descr>
<Letter>C</Letter>
<Percent>11%</Percent>
<RcptVATAmount>312,11</RcptVATAmount>
</VAT>
</NET_TAX_DATABASE>
```

I am trying to read the `VAT` nodes one by one to extract their `Percent` values, but it goes to the second node without reading the first node.  Here is my code, I don't know where the problem is:

```
var
  i,j      : Integer;
  aDoc     : TNativeXml;
  aNode    : TXmlNode;
begin
  try
    aDoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);
    aDoc.LoadFromStream(content);
    aDoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    if Assigned(aDoc.Root) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to aDoc.Root.NodeCount - 1 do
      begin
        if (AnsiUpperCase(aDoc.Root.Nodes[i].Name) = AnsiUpperCase('vat')) then
        begin
          aNode := aDoc.Root.Nodes[i];
          for j := 0 to aDoc.Root.NodeCount - 1 do
          begin
            if (aNode[j].Name = 'Percent') then
            begin
              str                  := aNode[j].ValueUnicode;
              str                  := stringReplace(str, '%','',[rfReplaceAll]);
              XReportInfo.PercTvaA := StrToInt(trim(str));
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    aDoc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

I am thinking to use this CODE node values but i don't know how?

Comment: It is not, that it *... goes to second node without read first VAT node.* You seem to assign the percentage value from both nodes to the same, one and only, `XReportInfo.PercTvaA`. Put a breakpoint on `for i := 0 to aDoc.Root.NodeCount - 1 do` and then step through the code line by line with **F8** and see how you are overwriting the value from the first node, with the value from the second.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop is using `aDoc.Root.NodeCount` when it should be using `aNode.NodeCount` instead.  `aDoc.Root.NodeCount` is 2, but there are more than 2 nodes in each `VAT`, and `Percent` is beyond the second node in each `VAT`, so your second loop will never see either of the `Percent` values.

Try something more like this instead:

```
var
  i,j   : Integer;
  aDoc  : TNativeXml;
  aNode : TXmlNode;
begin
  aDoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);
  try
    aDoc.LoadFromStream(content);
    aDoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    if Assigned(aDoc.Root) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to aDoc.Root.NodeCount - 1 do
      begin
        aNode := aDoc.Root.Nodes[i];
        if SameText(aNode.Name, 'VAT') then
        begin
          for j := 0 to aNode.NodeCount - 1 do
          begin
            if SameText(aNode[j].Name, 'Percent') then
            begin
              str := StringReplace(aNode[j].ValueUnicode, '%', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
              // use str as needed...
              Break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    aDoc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  i,j      : Integer;
  aDoc     : TNativeXml;
  aNode, aPercent : TXmlNode;
begin
  aDoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);
  try
    aDoc.LoadFromStream(content);
    aDoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    if Assigned(aDoc.Root) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to aDoc.Root.NodeCount - 1 do
      begin
        aNode := aDoc.Root.Nodes[i];
        if SameText(aNode.Name, 'VAT') then
        begin
          aPercent := aNode.NodeByName('Percent');
          if aPercent <> nil then
          begin
            str := StringReplace(aPercent.ValueUnicode, '%', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
            // use str as needed...
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    aDoc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  i,j      : Integer;
  aDoc     : TNativeXml;
  aList    : TList;
  aPercent : TXmlNode;
begin
  aDoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);
  try
    aDoc.LoadFromStream(content);
    aDoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    if Assigned(aDoc.Root) then
    begin
      aList := TList.Create;
      try
        aDoc.Root.FindNodes('Percent', aList);
        for i := 0 to aList.Count - 1 do
        begin
          aPercent := TXmlNode(aList[i]);
          str := StringReplace(aPercent.ValueUnicode, '%', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
          // use str as needed...
        end;
      finally
        aList.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    aDoc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "XML Data Binding Wizard" that comes with Delphi.
[Instructions here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_the_XML_Data_Binding_Wizard).

This tools generate a unit to parse the source file.
With this unit, a simple code like this, give you the percent of differents VAT elements.

```
var
  StockList: IXMLNET_TAX_DATABASEType;
  vat:IXMLVATType;
  i:integer;
begin
  StockList := LoadNET_TAX_DATABASE('sampleXML.xml');
  for I := 0 to (StockList.Count - 1) do begin
    vat := StockList.VAT[i];
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(vat.Code) +   ' -- ' + vat.Percent);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The XML Data Binding Wizard does not come with all editions (SKUs) of Delphi, and it's often overkill for small XML files. You should also include an alternative.